# Obtain an aware datetime object out of a string

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a way I can obtain a datetime aware object out of a string in Python using only the standard library modules ?

I know that I can use `dateutil.parser.parse`, but unfortunately that's not a good enough reason to add it as a dependency to my project. I already have the `mx.DateTime` module as a dependency, buuttttt:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2011-10-24T06:51:47-07:00')
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 24, 6, 51, 47, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))

>>> mx.DateTime.ISO.ParseDateTimeUTC('2011-10-24T06:51:47-07:00')
<mx.DateTime.DateTime object for '2011-10-24 13:51:47.00' at 29c7e48>
```

the `ParseDateTimeUTC` fails to detect the offset, even though in its documentation says that:

```
Returns a DateTime instance in UTC reflecting the given ISO
date. A time part is optional and must be delimited from the
date by a space or 'T'. Timezones are honored.
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the documentation. The timezone was honored and used to adjust the time to UTC. The resulting UTC time doesn't have a timezone because it isn't a local time anymore.

Comment: Doh, it makes sense now, I didn't look at the actual datetime string that ParseDateTimeUTC printed out ... if you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: To make things clear, I was looking for a stdlib/mx.DateTime parser that resembles a datetime object with the tzinfo field set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mx.DateTime.ISO.ParseDateTimeUTC` is doing the right thing - it is applying the specified timezone to adjust the time to UTC. The resulting UTC time doesn't have a timezone because it isn't a local time anymore.

The standard Python library doesn't contain *any* concrete timezone classes [according to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/datetime-tzinfo.html):

> tzinfo is an abstract base clase, meaning that this class should not
>   be instantiated directly. You need to derive a concrete subclass, and
>   (at least) supply implementations of the standard tzinfo methods
>   needed by the datetime methods you use. **The datetime module does not
>   supply any concrete subclasses of tzinfo.**

I've always been surprised that they didn't at least include a class for UTC, or a generic implementation like dateutil's `tzoffset`.